# Executing echo command in ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I want to execute `echo 'obase=94; 100' | bc >>out.txt` for that I have used

```
String[] cmd = {"echo" , "'obase=94; 100'" , " | bc"};
new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd).redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(new File("out.txt"))).start();
```

Inside `out.txt` I see `'obase=94; 100' | bc'` instead of `01 06`

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` needs to be interpreted by a shell.

```
String[] cmd = {"bash", "-c", "echo 'obase=94; 100' | bc"};
```

Comment: It worked. But can you explain it in detail? I mean what does `bash` and `-c` do,how it works etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9, one can use the `startPipeline` method of `ProcessBuilder` to "creat[e] a pipeline of processes linked by their standard output and standard input streams". (*c.f.* https://docs.oracle.com/javase//9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#startPipeline-java.util.List-)

```java
ProcessBuilder.startPipeline(Arrays.asList(
    new ProcessBuilder("echo" , "'obase=94; 100'"), 
    new ProcessBuilder("bc").redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(new File("out.txt")))
));
```